# Europass Resume Icons

Tags: symbols

How can I get vector image icons or LaTeX icons for the following resume template? Is there any default LaTeX `.cls` file that provide these icons (colorful icons for Windows). I would like to use similar icons in the following template. (to run this code you need few icon file that I created using Microsoft Visio).

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red,  urlcolor=blue}
    \usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.45in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \def\seticon#1{%
    \scalerel*{\includegraphics{#1}}{X}     % SCALES TO SIZE OF CAP {}
    %\scaleto{\includegraphics{#1}}{2.00ex} % SPECIFY THE HEIGHT OF THE SCALE
    }

    \usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx,xcolor,colortbl}

    % Thin Border Line Across Page (Page Setup)
    \usepackage{everypage}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{29,57,127}
    \def\PageTopMargin{1in}
    \def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
    \newcommand\atxy[3]{%
     \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{myblue!90}{#3}}}}}
    \atxy{0in}{0in}{\rule[-\paperheight]{6pt}{\paperheight}}

    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mdwlist}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumitem}% Used to control the spacing at enumerate (eg publication)
    \usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    {\huge \textsc{\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}}

    {Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} {\seticon{Linkedin_Logo.pdf} \href{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} {https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}\\
    {\seticon{EMail_Logo_Visio.pdf}    \href{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} or,      \seticon{EMail_Logo_Visio.pdf}     \href{xxxxxxxxxxxx}{xxxxxxxxxxxx}},    
    {\seticon{Phone_Logo_Visio.pdf}     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
    \end{center}




    \end{document}
```

[image: Sample Europass]

Comment: Yes. See [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome).

Comment: I have seen fontawesome but those are not colorful.. Fontawesome only provides black&white icons.  Thanks

Comment: It provides the shapes... you can choose the colour. How about you provide the community with a sample document and layout. That way we (the community) can focus on the question - adding those elements. We'd hate to provide you with a solution after which you mention that it doesn't fit within your framework...

Comment: I added a sample code in the question section.. Thanks

Comment: A while back I started playing with creating a class for the new europass style but could not find the time to finish it. However, what I did have the time to do was to create a font with the icons for it. It is available on github at https://github.com/ArTourter/europass if you are interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using some icons from [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,fontawesome}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{29,57,127}
\newcommand{\seticon}[1]{\textcolor{myblue}{\csname #1\endcsname}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c@{~}l@{~}l}
    \seticon{faMapMarker}      & Address:  & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\
    \seticon{faPhone}          & Phone:    & xxx-xxx-xxxx \\
    \seticon{faAt}             & Email:    & xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.xxx \\
    \seticon{faChain}          & Website:  & xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx \\
    \seticon{faLinkedinSquare} & LinkedIn: & xxxxxxxx \\
    \seticon{faComment}        & IM:       & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so  much. I am facing some error ( Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H <return>.) May you please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: @ibrahimkbd: Removing the loading of [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) and compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't find the $fontspec$ part in the code you provided.

Comment: @ibrahimkbd: Yes, I didn't use `fontspec`, nor does it seem like you're using it in the code you provided. So why would you get a `fontspec` error?

Comment: I tried to run your code only however i am facing the same error. Plz see the error details (Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H <return>.)

Comment: @ibrahimkbd: You may be using an old version of [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) which *requires* the use of [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec). The more recent (current) version works with `pdflatex`. So, update your distribution by following the instructions listed in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)